# Como agrego un mapa meteorologico de Open Weather Map?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando agregar un mapa meteorologico de temperatura de Open Weather Map y no consigo nada, ya busque y no encuentro respuestas, ademas en la documentacion no encontre ejemplos claros.
aqui estan fragmentos de mi codigo:

Esta es la funcion principal funciona correctamente y manda a llamar la funcion que tengo problemas

```js
const consultaClima = async () => {
  //Funcion consultaClima
  const urlForecast = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${inputCiudad.value}&appid=60b8cc4849c0ce289f96fe055bdd008b&units=metric&lang=es`;
  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${inputCiudad.value}&lang=sp&appid=60b8cc4849c0ce289f96fe055bdd008b&units=metric&cnt=6`;
  try {
    console.log(`esperando...`);
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(`tarea completa`);
    const idIcon = data.weather[0].icon;
    const iconUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/img/w/${idIcon}.png`;
    pintarInfo(data, iconUrl);
    crearMapMet(data)         //Esta es la funcion con problemas
    crearMap(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`hubo un error`,error);
  }
};
```

Y aqui esta la funcion que no funciona correctamente:

```js
const crearMapMet = async (data) => {
  const mapMet = document.getElementById(`mapMet`)
  const lon = data.coord.lon
  const lat = data.coord.lat
  const url = `https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/10/${lat}/${lon}.png?appid=60b8cc4849c0ce289f96fe055bdd008b`
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(url)
    const imagen = await resp.blob()
    const urlImagen = URL.createObjectURL(imagen)
    const mapaMet = document.createElement(`img`)
    mapaMet.src = urlImagen
    mapaMet.id = `mapaMet`
    mapMet.appendChild(mapaMet)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error al cargar el mapa:', error);
  }
}
```